# INNER JOIN where **every** row must match the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, exists

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. I have two tables, A and B.

```
A          B
-----      -----
id         id
name       a_id
           value
```

I want to select only the rows from A where ALL the values of the rows from B match a where clause. Something like:

```
SELECT * from A INNER JOIN B on B.a_id = A.id WHERE B.value > 2
```

The problem with the above query is that if ANY row from B has a value > 2 I'll get the corresponding row from A, and I only want the row from A if

1.) **ALL** the rows in B **for B.a_id = A.id** match the WHERE, **OR**

2.) There are no rows in B that reference A

B is basically a table of filters.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: Your definition is **contradictory**. If you have more than one distinct value in `a.id` it is **impossible** for `ALL the rows in B match the WHERE`, because a row in `B` cannot have more than one value at a time. Please clarify. It would seem you mean: *Return all rows from `A`, where all rows in `B` **that match on `B.a_id = A.id`** also fulfill the second condition `B.value > 2`.*

Comment: You're right, @ErwinBrandstetter, I had the constraint that B.a_id = A.id in mind. Edited to clarify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    b
        WHERE   b.a_id = a.a_id
                AND (b.value <= 2 OR b.value IS NULL)
        )
```

Comment: You can also write the query like this if you chose to use `EXISTS` logic over join `SELECT * FROM a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT  1
        FROM    b
        WHERE   b.a_id = a.a_idAND (IFNULL(b.value, 0) <= 2)`

Answer (score 3):

Answering this question (which it seems you actually meant to ask):

*Return all rows from `A`, where all rows in `B` with `B.a_id = A.id` also pass the test `B.value > 2`.*

Which is equivalent to:

*Return all rows from `A`, where no row in `B` with `B.a_id = A.id` fails the test `B.value > 2`.*

```
SELECT a.*  --  "rows from A" (so don't include other columns)
FROM   a
LEFT   JOIN b ON b.a_id = a.id
             AND (b.value > 2) IS NOT TRUE  -- safe inversion of logic
WHERE  b.a_id IS NULL;
```

When inverting a `WHERE` condition carefully consider null values. [**`IS NOT TRUE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html) is the **simple and safe way** to perfectly invert a `WHERE` condition. The alternative would be `(b.value <= 2 OR b.value IS NULL)` which is longer but may be faster (easier to support with index).

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem:

```
SELECT *
FROM   a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   b
                   WHERE  b.a_id = a.id
                   AND    b.value <= 2)
```

Here is the way in which this is obtained.

Suppose that we have available a universal quantifier (parallel to EXISTS, the existential quantifier), with a syntax like:

```
FORALL table WHERE condition1 : condition2
```

(to be read: FORALL the elements of table that satisfy the condition1, then condition2 is true)

So you could write your query in this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM   a
WHERE  FORALL b WHERE b.a_id = a.id : b.value > 2
```

(Note that forall is true even when no element in b exists with a value of a.id)

Then we can transform the universal quantifier in the existential one, with a double negation, as usual:

```
SELECT *
FROM   a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS b WHERE b.a_id = a.id : NOT (b.value > 2)
```

In plain SQL this can be written as:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM   b 
                  WHERE  b.a_id = a.id
                  AND    (b.value > 2) IS NOT TRUE)
```

This technique is very handy in case of universal quantification.

Comment: Only NULL is not considered.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON B.a_id = A.id
WHERE B.value > 2 OR B.a_id IS NULL
```

Comment: This will return a row if there is but a single entry in `B` which matches the filter for `a_id`, regardless of other entries which don't

Comment: This query should return all the records in A that do not exists in B and have value > 2 which is what the OP is asking for

Comment: the op is asking that **all** the rows in B match the `WHERE`. Your query will return if **any** row in `B` matches the `WHERE`, or if there are no rows in `B` for this `a_id`.

Comment: I am not sure if I misunderstood the 2 conditions "1.) All the rows in B match the WHERE, OR 2)There are no rows in B that reference A"

Comment: say there are two entries in `b (a_id, value)`: (1, 1), (1, 3). Op does not want `a_id = 1` to return.

Comment: `2)There are no rows in B that reference A` tell me that he want all the row in B if there is no match in B + anything that have a match in B but have a value > 2  if this is not that the OP is requesting I suggest that he put a jFiddle together with dummy data so we know what to recommend

Comment: I only want to select the row from A if **ALL** the rows from B that reference A have a value > 2. **OR** if there are no rows from B that reference A.

Comment: @jhickner my query should do just that. Please give it a shot a let me know the result. you should put example data and your expected results in your question

Comment: Not it doesn't. you return all columns from A and B, possibly multiple combinations (multiplying A), irregardless of whether there are offending rows in B for the same a_id. This couldn't me more wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON b.a_id = a.id
WHERE B.a_id IS NULL OR NOT EXIST (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    b
        WHERE  b.value <= 2)
```

Comment: This is invalid syntax (no join condition).

Comment: An now it's invalid logic :) Any single row with `b.value = 1` would remove all rows from A with *any* match in B on `b.a_id = a.id`.

Comment: 1.) ALL the rows in B match the WHERE, OR (in this case if b.value = 1 then not all the rows in B will match the where) so it will try to make the second case true

2.) There are no rows in B that reference A,..... Where there is no row referencing A meaning B.a_id is null. That's what the requirements are in the question!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.is, a.name, c.id as B_id, c.value from A 
INNER JOIN (Select b.id, b.a_id, b.value from B WHERE B.value > 2) C
on C.a_id = A.id
```

Note it is a poor practice to use select *. You shoudl only specify fields you need. IN this case, I might possibly remove the b.Id refernces becasue they are probably not needed. If you have a join there is a 100% chance you are wasting resouces sending data you don't need becasue the join fields will be repeated.  That is why I did nto include a_id in the final result set.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer not to use `EXISTS`, you can use an outer join.

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM 
    A 
    LEFT JOIN B ON 
        B.a_id = A.id 
        AND B.value <= 2 -- note: condition reversed!!
WHERE B.id IS NULL
```

This works by searching for the existence of a failing record in `B`.  If it finds one, then the join will match, and the final `WHERE` clause will exclude that record.

Comment: Only NULL is not considered.